# How to disabled button after clicking and it only click once?

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 8. I have two buttons `punchIn` and `punchOut`. After clicking `punchIn` button it will have to disable. How to do it?

Comment: Add [disable]='clicked' to button ..create a flag 'clicked' and set it to true when it is clicked...

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/simm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @TriveniMali What you have tried till now? plz share code.

Comment: created punchIn and punchOut function all are working only want to disabled punchIn button after clicking once @Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your component ts :-**

```
export class AppComponent  {
    isPunchInDisable = false;
    isPunchOutDisable = false;

    punchIn() {
     this.isPunchInDisable = true;
    }
    punchOut() {
     this.isPunchOutDisable = true;
    }
}
```

**In you HTML:-**

```
<button [disabled]="isPunchInDisable " (click)="punchIn()">Puch in</button>
<button [disabled]="isPunchOutDisable " (click)="punchOut()">Puch Out</button>
```

Basically the `isPunchInDisable` and `isPunchOutDisable` varibles holds the state of the disabling of the buttons

Comment: and also want button disabled after refreshing the page

Comment: I applied your logic its working. but how to keep that button disabled after refresh the page.

Comment: will you give me any example to how to keep state in the local storage?

Answer (score 1):

In your component.ts file, create a variable `setDisable`. Change this variable's value to `true` on the click of the button **Punch In**.

```
export class AppComponent  {
    setDisable = false;

    punchIn() {
     this.setDisable = true;
    }
}
```

Your button HTML

```
<button [disabled]="setDisable" (click)="punchIn()">Puch in</button>
```